# Building 2-Axis Charts on multiple Excel worksheets in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops, plot

Using VBA in Excel I am trying to loop through all worksheets and plot data in the same place for each sheet.  This will use 4 columns out of 10 to build a two axis plot. The following code successfully loops and plots, however only the first and last sheets are correctly constructed. The other sheets plot all 10 columns rather than just the desired sets.

```
Sub plotLoop()

' Declare Current as a worksheet object variable.
Dim Current As Worksheet

' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
For Each Current In Worksheets
    Current.Select
    Current.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets(Current.Name).Range("$A$17:$A$350")
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Sheets(Current.Name).Range("$B$17:$B$350")
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = Sheets(Current.Name).Range("$I$17:$I$350")
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = Sheets(Current.Name).Range("$J$17:$J$350")
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 2
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
    Selection.Caption = "Time(S)"
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleRotated)
    Selection.Caption = "Units(u)"
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementLegendNone)
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    Selection.Caption = "Rolling Charts"
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run your code with no errors.

should be a "selection" issue, to catch it you must run your code in debug mode stepping through every codeline and checking for actual variable values.

I hereby attach an alternative coding style of your sub that makes no use of selections, which should give you more grasp on what object you're actually dealing with and, hopefully, lead to any error

```
Sub plotLoop2()

' Declare Current as a worksheet object variable.
Dim Current As Worksheet

Dim X1Range As Range, Y1Range As Range, X2Range As Range, Y2Range As Range
Dim series1 As Series, series2 As Series

Const X1Address As String = "$A$17:$A$350"
Const Y1Address As String = "$B$17:$B$350"
Const X2Address As String = "$I$17:$I$350"
Const Y2Address As String = "$J$17:$J$350"
' should those not be constants, then comment the four lines above and uncomment the following five lines
'Dim X1Address As String, Y1Address As String, X2Address As String, Y2Address As String
'X1Address = "$A$17:$A$350"
'Y1Address = "$B$17:$B$350"
'X2Address = "$I$17:$I$350"
'Y2Address = "$J$17:$J$350"

' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
For Each Current In Worksheets

    With Current
        'set current sheet X-Y ranges
        Set X1Range = .Range(X1Address)
        Set Y1Range = .Range(Y1Address)
        Set X2Range = .Range(X2Address)
        Set Y2Range = .Range(Y2Address)

        .Shapes.AddChart
        With .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)

            Set series1 = addOneSeries(.Chart, X1Range, Y1Range)
            Set series2 = addOneSeries(.Chart, X2Range, Y2Range)

            With .Chart
                .ChartType = xlXYScatter

                .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
                .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Caption = "Time(S)"

                .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleRotated)
                .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Caption = "Units(u)"

                .HasLegend = False

                .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
                .ChartTitle.Caption = "Rolling Charts"
            End With

            series1.AxisGroup = 2


        End With
    End With
Next
End Sub


Function addOneSeries(myChart As Chart, XRange As Range, YRange As Range) As Series
With myChart
    Set addOneSeries = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With addOneSeries
        .XValues = XRange
        .Values = YRange
    End With
End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me find my problem. I had to include a make sure make each sheet active in the loop as well.

Comment: glad to be of help.  as for the making sure about the active sheet, I run the code I posted with no need of that. but chartobjects and chart objects can be quite a pain according to actual needs.  If you care, post your code and  I'll try to make it "selection/activation free"